# What are some techniques for handling security in a Single-Page Angular Application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I am trying to build a single page application using Angular for my front-end development, and WebAPI 2.0 for my server-side objects and controllers. What are some recommended techniques for handling security. For example, (1) how can I prevent a user from elevating their role, via manipulation of the client-side source? Or, (2) how can I prevent a user from making api calls, say to api/users, when they should not be allowed to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WebAPI you are in luck because it integrates directly with host authentication and authorization modules. You can use any of the built-in authentication modules (anonymous, basic, integrated, etc.) or write your own. For example, if you have custom permissions you can use those to update IPrincipal/IIdentity and take appropriate action to only return results based on what is allowed for the user. You can also take full advantage of Authorization Filters. There is more information here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

As for the client-side code, there are a few things you can do there. If you are using WebAPI chances are you have MVC available to serve the pages. In that case, you can secure access to resources like you would in a typical MVC application, so users are not able to navigate to content they should not have access to. That takes care never rendering portions of secured content so the user can never "hack the client" to see something they shouldn't.

On the client itself you may have pages that expose various controls based on permissions. There, you can store permissions on the client-side and use directives to show or hide content (in some cases you might even take content rendered from the server and truncate it for performance reasons so it is never compiled if it won't be displayed). Again, this is something that happens on the client but still doesn't expose security because the actual data to bind to the nodes comes through the secured APIs.